# How to select a set of pandas rows, where the sum of each column is approximately the same or around a given number?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

Suppose there is a dataframe of mxn like:

```
    a   b   c   d
0  19  13  14  19
1  13   6   6  10
2   2  16  12  26
3   8   2   9  27
4  16   6  10  22
5   6  14  14  26
6  18   8   8  22
7   8  11   7  18
8  16  12  12  23
9  14  19   5  11
```

How to randomly select a number of rows, that the sum of each column is approximately the same or around a given number?

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, it may be very hard to find a solution in case the standard deviation among columns is high, so it can be only an approximation rather than a fixel solution.

Comment: What is the given number ?

Comment: And how many rows?

Comment: Why randomly? .. first step is to be able to isolate all the rows that match your requirements and second step is to randomly select from that set.

Comment: And if the standard deviation between rows is high, it can be difficult to find a solution.

Comment: @BENY, It can be any k, with k<m.

Comment: @JimmyNJ I want to do it randomly in order to not insert some bias in the numbers distributions. But it can be not-randomly.

Comment: @Corralien I agree, but in this case an approximation can suffice...